# Flutter: how to get the http response header

Tags: flutter

The way I tried to post a data to the server, and then the server return the detail message which is encapsulated in response header for me, how to get this message out of response header?

```
var response = await http.post(...);
var detail_message = response['header'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response-class.html

```
var response = await http.post(...);
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.headers}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');
```

Answer (score 1):

You must decode your response data if header response

```
var decodedData = jsonDecode(response);
var detail_message = decodedData['header'];
```

Otherwise:

```
var detail_message = response.headers;
```